# Remove padding in a matplotlib line plot that already uses set_axis_off, bbox_inches=tight and pad_inches=0?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some data as an image of a given size (for use as an overlay). However, despite calling `set_axis_off()` and setting `bbox_inches="tight"` and `pad_inches=0` on `savefig` (as suggested in other questions), I still get padding, and a larger image size than the figsize should result in.

Here's the code (the PIL dependency is for ease of use but can be removed by removing the last line):

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_box(data, size, filename="plot.png"):
    """Plot the data in an image whose dimensions are size x size pixels"""
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(size/100,size/100), dpi=100)
    ax = fig.add_axes((0,0,1,1))
    ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.plot(data)
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    plt.savefig(filename, bbox_inches="tight", pad_inches=0, dpi='figure', transparent=True)
    plt.close()
    return Image.open(filename)
```

However, regardless of the size I specify, the images are always either 6 or 7 pixels wider in both directions:

```
>> data = [i**2 for i in range(-100, 101)]
>> plot_box(data, 50)
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=57x57 at 0xED3CB38>
>> plot_box(data, 100)
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=106x106 at 0xF208908>
>> plot_box(data, 1)
<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=8x8 at 0x53D2748>
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

Here's the resulting image from `plot_box(data, 100)`. As you can see, it looks fine other than being larger than expected due to padding (106x106 rather than 100x100).

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the image you get, and an example of how you would like it to look?

Comment: I've added the resulting padded plot. Due to the white background here it's clearer when you click on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `bbox_inches="tight"` from the `savefig` call. You then also don't need `pad_inches`.

```
plt.savefig(filename, dpi='figure', transparent=True)
```

This will result in an image of 100x100 pixels.

If you also don't want to have any margin inside the axes, set it to 0,

```
ax.margins(0)
```